# 18.10 - Laptop Touchpad - Two Finger Click and Drag Stops Working After Update

Tags: mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, input, mousepad

I have come across an issue with clicking and dragging on my Lenovo L380 laptop. On a fresh install or using the Live CD/USB I am able to physically click the touchpad with one finger and then drag with another finger to do a selection. Though immediately after doing an apt upgrade and a reboot on the laptop that functionality ceases. I can no longer move the mouse with the second finger after clicking down on the touchpad with the first finger. I presume something with the mouse/input was updated but I cannot figure out what was changed or how to change it back. It occurs using for X11 and Wayland after the upgrade, it works before upgrading in X11 (I did not test to see if it worked in Wayland before the upgrade).

Has anyone else run into this and if so, how did you fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does it continue to not work if you reboot more? Have you tried updating again? Have you checked the GUI menu for mouse settings?

Comment: Yes it does not matter how many times I reboot. There are no more updates to run so I cannot update again. I have checked the mouse settings, no options change the functionality. The fact that it is a fresh install and the only thing that changes is a software update indicates to me that something in the update changed something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Open the terminal and run this command you will be prompted to the text editor.

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Here you have to replace

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quit splash"
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quit splash i8042.nopnp"
```

And reboot your system it will probably start working.

Hope it Helps.